# Suggested schema to store Stock Prices

Tags: mysql, stocks

I've exhausted my google-fu and cannot get anything like an answer, so I thought I'd ask here.

[background]
I run a forum centered around an American Football based video game (BloodBowl). Each member has their own team, and we run leagues and cups. I thought it would be fun to write some 'stocks and shares' functionality for a site, so each member can invest in other teams. Prices would update after each game is played (~100 games per week), but the actual update would be asynchronous (I have current code triggering at the correct time, so it can be modified to incorporate what is needed.
[/background]

Basically, I need to record the prices that each team (asset) has at each change, updated asynchronously but only once per week. With 200 teams, and 12 weeks to a season, I'd be looking at 2400 records per season (and this will run into infinity, though weeks are real-life weeks, so not *too* big).

My thinking is a single table, such as :

`[teamID] Int`
`[price] Int`
`[date] Date`
`[dividend] Int`
`[gain] Int`
`[gain%] float(2dp)`
`[comment] Text`

Which row(s) should be my primary key?

Am I over-thinking this? Should I just code it? My worry is that I want to be able to get historical data, for example for graphs and such, though I would be hitting this table very regularly as players trade stocks. I don't want to code it and later realise that I'm missing some field that would make all of my queries massively more efficient.

What I suppose I'm really looking for is the schema used by some db that actually uses this for stocks in real life, just to model it in a similar way.

Thanks for reading, and I hope that somebody has some input here.

Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at any online portfolio trackers?

Mine has the following columns:

```
Name▲▼ Symbol▲▼ Last price▲▼ Change▲▼ Shares▲▼ Cost basis▲▼ Mkt value▲▼ Gain▲▼ Gain %▲▼ Day's gain▲▼ Overall return
```

Hope this helps some...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll add the gain info to the table, as its the only one relevant to what I'm doing.

Comment: Don't I get an upvote for that contribution to your design? ;)